# python nested function, missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, typeerror, positional-argument

I am learning python from the beginning. Just start to learn nested functions.
These days I got some good code as below:

```
def w(m , g): 
    return m * g
def weight(g):
    def cal_mg(m):
        return m * g
    return cal_mg
w = weight(10)
G = w(100)
G2 = w(50)
print(G)
```

It gives me "1000", which I have no problem with. When I start to learn this, I wrote:

```
   def w(m, g): 
       return m*g
   def weight(g):
       def cal_mg(m):
           return m*g
       return cal_mg
   w_1=weight(10)
   G=w(100)
   print(G)
```

I got "TypeError: w() missing 1 required positional argument: 'g'". I feel like I was typing the exactly same code. Why it keeps asking about another argument 'g'.

Anyone can help me with this? thanks

Comment: The "good" code overwrote the name `w`.  But you assigned to `w_1`.

Comment: in your first example you overwrite your `w` to be the result of your `weight` function that happens to be a function of one argument, in your second example you don't do that so `w` remains as a function of 2 arguments that need them both to be called

Comment: Thanks, guys, I got it now.  Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you referenced function `w` as well, which requires, as you stated, `g` and `m`.

```
   def w(m, g): 
       return m*g
   def weight(g):
       def cal_mg(m):
           return m*g
       return cal_mg
   w_1=weight(10)
   G=w(100, 100)
   print(G)
```

would be a possible solution; this way you satisfy all requirements. Function `weight` only requires ```g``.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the first example you are filling both the positional arguments. That is once in line 7 when u assign the weight function to w and the second time in line 8 when u assign G to w with the positional argument of 100. So it returns 10*100. Whereas, in the second code u just assign w_1 to the weight function with positional argument 10 which python interprets it to be for the place holder m and the argument for g is missing. Hence u got the error.